# Excel - Return column reference from row and column criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have a dataset looking at ratings over time:

```
A     B          C         D          E 
ID   Date     Rating-1   Rating-2   Rating-3
1   01/01/20               Y
2   01/05/19     Y
3   15/12/19               Y
```

I want to extract the rating for a particular ID at a particular date. As the rating is not specified in the data (as each is represented by a `Y` value), I need to reference either the column heading or the column reference.
To get the relevant row, I can use a `Match` formula:
`=MATCH(1,(1=$A$1:$A$4)*(DATE(2020,01,01)=$B$1:$B$4),0)` - this will give row 2.

To get the column reference for a specific row, I can use a second `Match` formula: `=MATCH("Y",$A3:$E3,0)` - this will give column 4.

Is there a way to combine the two formulas to give me the column reference for a specified row (based on ID/Date criteria) and a specified column (the column with a `Y` value)?

I have tried a `Index Match Match` formula, but this seems to require the column reference to be specified, rather than finding a column with a `Y` value.

Comment: Can [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) help you maybe?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey - thanks, I incorporated `INDIRECT` into the solution I posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid `INDIRECT` as it's volatile! There are other options such as below:

```
=INDEX(A1:E1,MATCH("Y",INDEX(A1:E4,MATCH(1,INDEX((A1:A4=1)*(B1:B4=DATE(2,020,1,1)),),0),0),0))
```

BTW, the nested `INDEX` is there to avoid necessity to CSE the formula. If you have ExcelO365 this could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using `INDIRECT`, `CONCATENATE` and `MATCH`:
`{=MATCH("Y",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$A",MATCH(1,(1=$A$1:$A$4)*(DATE(2020,01,01)=$B$1:$B$4),0),":$E",MATCH(1,(1=$A$1:$A$4)*(DATE(2020,01,01)=$B$1:$B$4),0))),0)}`

Effectively, the `CONCATENATE` and `INDIRECT` parts of the formula creates a range specified by ID and Date criteria. This range takes the form of a single row in which to the `MATCH` function then searches for the `Y` value and returns the column number.